# Wordpress WP_Query tricks to avoid duplicated posts

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'd like to implement infinite posts functionality using `WP_Query` function.
There are two divs in page.

When you scroll down to the bottom every div loads more its own posts like newest or its own categories posts.

But I don't want to load duplicated posts (i.e., if you load newest posts in div1, while div 2 load posts by category, some posts could be loaded in two divs).

How can I avoid this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send data about the loaded divs in ajax request on scroll. On php side you need to do something like this:

```
$exclude_ids = '1,2,3';
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__not_in' => array( $exclude_ids ) ) );
```